# Best way to check if ubuntu service has stopped in c#

Tags: c#, azure, ubuntu-16.04

I want to get an alert when a service (grafana or influxdb) in an Azure virtual machine (Ubuntu 16.04) has stopped. I'd like to use c# to connect to the VM and check the status of grafana and influxdb services. Can anyone share a code sample that implements this?

Comment: Please show us what options you have tried

Comment: You don't need to connect and check something yourself. Azure Monityoring [has a Linux agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-collect-linux-computer) that can collect metrics, service status etc from any Linux VMs. Grafana has [an Azure Monitor](https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-azure-monitor-datasource) plugin that can be used to monitor health and its behaviour.

Comment: Azure Monitor can [check HTTP endpoint responsiveness with ping tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability) and InfluxDB offers [such an endpoint](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/api/#ping-http-endpoint). You could add a generic ping test if there's no better solution

Comment: You can configure alerts and get notified immediatelly when a service goes down, you could call Azure Monitor to see the status of the services, or, worst case, you could call `ping` endpoints from your code. This would have to be secured in some way to prevent hackers from pinging the services to death, eg by only allowing access from specific IPs.

Comment: Oops, that Grafana plugin is for using Azure Monitor as a source. Grafana [does have a health endpoint though](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/other/#health-api). So, in the simplest case, one could write a C# program that just calls the health URLs of both services periodically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both services provide health endpoints that can be used to check their status from a remote server. There's no need to open a remote shell connection. In fact, it would be impossible to monitor large server farms if one had to SSH to each one.

In the simplest case, and ignoring networking issues, one can simply hit the health endpoints to check the status of both services. A rough implementation could look like this :

```
public async Task<bool> CheckBoth()
{
    var client = new HttpClient
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
    };

    const string grafanaHealthUrl = "https://myGrafanaURL/api/health";
    const string influxPingUrl = "https://myInfluxURL/ping";

    var (grafanaOK, grafanaError) = await CheckAsync(client, grafanaHealthUrl,
                                                     HttpStatusCode.OK, "Grafana error");
    var (influxOK, influxError) = await CheckAsync(client, influxPingUrl, 
                                                   HttpStatusCode.NoContent,"InfluxDB error");

    if (!influxOK || !grafanaOK)
    {
                //Do something with the errors
                return false;
    }
    return true;

}

public async Task<(bool ok, string result)> CheckAsync(HttpClient client,
                                                       string healthUrl, 
                                                       HttpStatusCode expected,
                                                       string errorMessage)
{
    try
    {
        var status = await client.GetAsync(healthUrl);
        if (status.StatusCode != expected)
        {
            //Failure message, get it and log it
            var statusBody = await status.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //Possibly log it ....
            return (ok: false, result: $"{errorMessage}: {statusBody}");
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        return (ok: false, result: $"{errorMessage}: Timeout");
    }
    return (ok: true, "");
}
```

Perhaps a better solution would be to use Azure Monitor to [ping the health URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-alert#create-availability-test) periodically and send an alert if they are down.

Comment: I still have to check if using Azure Monitor as you say is a better solution in my case, but the code example works for me. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can use to connect to Azure linux using SSH in c#

```js
using (var client = new SshClient("my-vm.cloudapp.net", 22, "username", "password​"))
        {
            client.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("it worked!");
            client.Disconnect();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Usually SSH server only allow public key auth or other two factor auth.

Change your /etc/ssh/sshd_configuncomment #PasswordAuthentication yes

```
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
 #PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Later you can poll for installed services.

**Also for an alternative solution, you can deploy a rest api in your linux VM to check the status of your service  and the call it from C# httpclient for the status.**

Hope it helps

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use  Azure healtcheck services to check the status of grafana and influxdb?

Comment: Yes that can be doable but User requires c# code to check the status.

Comment: Those services can be checked with HTTP using any language. In any case, simply connecting to the VM doesn't check the status of the services.

Comment: Yes that's what i mentioned in my alternative solution :)

Comment: Why write and deploy an agent for example, when Log Analytics already has a Linux agent? Users can query the log data to see what's going on through HTTP, although it's better to configure an alert that fires when the services are down

Comment: Yes that would be the best way indeed to simply configure the alert for the azure services.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me because there is an issue with SSH.Net API when password contains "@".

Comment: The i would suggest you to use Azure monitor for health check, That is indeed quite easy and sufficient way .